# Why laravel returns class not exist error? However everything seems fine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created service in the `app/services` folder and I'm using it controller. In the services folder I have the following.

```php
namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class SubscriptionService
{
    private $subUsername = 'M****************b';
    private $subPassword = 'V********g';
    private $subSource = 'o*********k';
    private $subMinisite = 'a*******m';

    public function pinVerify($request)
    {
        $DataArray = [];
        $client = new Client();
        $route = 'http://b*******e.com/****/P***y.php';
        $params = [
            'form_params' => [
                'Username' => $this->subUsername,
                'Password' => $this->subPassword,
                'userID' => $request->user_id,
                'pincode' => $request->pin_code,
            ]
        ];

        $result = $client->request('POST', $route, $params);
        $body = $result->getBody();

        $bodyContent = $body->getContents();
        if ($bodyContent === 1) {
            $DataArray['message'] = 'Failed because of system error';
            $DataArray['status'] = 'failed';
        } else {
            $DataArray['message'] = 'Sorry provided pincode is wrong.';
            $DataArray['status'] = 'failed';
        }

        return $DataArray;
    }
}
```

In the controller, I am using it in one method like below.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\SubscriptionService as Subscription;

class XyzController extends Controller
{
    public function verifyPinCode(Subscription $Subscription, Request $request){
        $serviceResponse = $Subscription->pinVerify($request);
        return response()->json($serviceResponse, 200); 
    }
}
```

In the result I am getting the error `Class does not exist.` I am not sure where I am making a mistake. Can someone kindly guide me on how to fix the issue?

**Error**

```
ReflectionException
Class App\Services\SubscriptionService does not exist
Previous exceptions
syntax error, unexpected ''pincode'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
```

**Composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

[image]

Comment: try  `composer update`, then `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: can you show your `composer.json` autoloading part?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari I added in the question, kindly check it

Comment: I did the same, instead of codes just echoing `Hello World` in the controller, working fine for me, no need of `composer dump-autoload`. I recommend you to have look on the names of the classes and files.

Comment: first fix this error `syntax error, unexpected ''pincode'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`'

Comment: When do you get it after hitting url to the controller's method?

Comment: Yes when I execute that method only then laravel returns error

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of the error? You can upload here https://imgbb.com/

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari I added a picture, kindly check it

Comment: upload full image there please

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems okay. Try giving the command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra space or something after given line.
I have checked your code and just hit a backspace after this line `'userID'        => $request->user_id,​`and your syntax error, unexpected ''pincode'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) error is gone

Answer (score 0):

The `syntax error, unexpected ''pincode'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` means that you have a parsing issue (extra character or missing character or something like that) in the file of `SubscriptionService` class. Therefore, the file is not parsed and the class is not available. The exception error trace is clear about that. Find the issue and solve it. You problem will be solved.